# Android - clear the recent app list (shown after long HOME press)

Tags: android, homescreen, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I'm writing a custom launcher app. The problem is even after setting it as default, the long press of HOME button brings recent app list, including old launcher.

Is it possible to clear the recent app list?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list

Comment: Solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258980/altering-the-result-of-getrecenttasks