# How to remove or kill an application from recent apps list?

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I'm developing an app which will be used by children.

I took over the home button by making my app a launcher.
Now I'm trying to take over the long press of the home button which brings up the recent apps list.

I searched for and tried:

- taking over the button
- clearing the apps list
- killBackgroundProcesses() and Process.killProcess()

I'm able to get the tasks by ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(), but I can't seem to clear it in any way.

I've come across two possible solutions:

- listening to onWindowFocusChanged and Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS => this is not an acceptable answer for my requirements
- doing it like ToddlerLock and flood the apps list with activities => this is a hack and in the future it might not work anymore

Is there another possibility (except building a custom rom) or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:
I was able to kill other running processes but their entry remained in the recent apps list, so if you click it, it will just restart that application.
Is there a way to refresh that list?

EDIT 2:
I tried to do it like ToddlerLock and followed the directions of [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258980/altering-the-result-of-getrecenttasks).
I've got 18 dummy activities running and showing in the recent apps list, but this doesn't block the possibility to click previous active apps.
Any help?

Comment: I am also fighting with the recent apps list on Android 4.1, but in my case it is about preventing my app from being "swipe killed" - did you prevent it somehow? Whatever you do, your app will always be shown on first position of the list...
It would be best to block the list at all - "avast! Mobile Security" does that on its anti-theft screen, but I don't know yet how to do that - maybe it has to work as a lock screen somehow? That's a clue only, maybe it will help you somehow

Comment: I believe there are several ways for your app to prevent it from showing in the recent apps list: the easiest is putting this in your manifest 'android:excludeFromRecents="true"' that should work. Mine doesn't show up in the list because mine is set as a launcher.

Blocking or clearing the list is indeed what I want to achieve, the lock screen might be an option but I already made it into a launcher and tend to keep it that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258980/altering-the-result-of-getrecenttasks